# How does \delimiter work? How does it convert its argument into character(s?) and why?

Tags: math-mode, macros, tex-core

studying the definition of `\lvert` (which just made me finally understand what does mean `\@xp\@gobble` and how it works \o/), I found the `\delimiter` command, with a numeric argument advanced by 0x1000000… So if I well understood delimiter translates into one character according its numerical argument… with something depending wether we’re inside mathmode or not… Well how does this number translate into something (where’s the translation table?), how is it related with mathmode and what does thi advancement by 0x1000000 mean/implies? And finally what’s the purpose of `\delimiter`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`\vert` in latex is defined by

```
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\vert}
   {\mathord}{symbols}{"6A}{largesymbols}{"0C}
```

which says that it is an ordinary delimiter (not open or close) that at its natural size is taken from the symbol fonts (starting at) position hex 6A with larger sizes taken from the largesymbol font (starting at) position hex 0C.

We can look at the plain TeX definition of the same.

```
\def\vert{\delimiter"26A30C }
```

which is more compact but perhaps less readable.

`\delimiter` is a number which packs a bit code which we can decode by splitting up the hex digits

0 (not shown) = `\mathord`

2  = symbol font

6A = symbol font slot

3 =  extension (large symbol) font

0C = Slot in large symbol font.

`amsmath` defines `lvert` to be an "opening" version of `vert` which could have been

```
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\lvert}
   {\mathopen}{symbols}{"6A}{largesymbols}{"0C}
```

but to allow for possible different font encodings it uses the primitive syntax and just adds "4000000  so the leading hex digit is 4 not 0 denoting a mathopen.

the tfm font metrics associate with the math fonts specify how delimiters stretch, starting from the specified slots the metrics chain together a sequence of larger glyphs then finally how to build an arbitrarily large character by stacking top bottom (possibly middle, for `{`) and repeatable segments.

To see the metric information taking an example and the plain tex versions the `3` means `\fam3` which is defined by

```
\textfont3=\tenex
```

which says fam3 is `\tenex` which is defined by

```
\font\tenex=cmex10 % math extension
```

so we can look at the metrics of `cmex10` using the comand

```
 tftopl cmex10.tfm > cmex10.pl
```

the `.pl` property list being a readable form of the font metrics.

hex OC is Octal 12 and in the pl file you see

```
(CHARACTER O 12
   (CHARWD R 0.472224)
   (CHARHT R 0.039999)
   (CHARDP R 1.160013)
   (NEXTLARGER O 104)
   )
```

which tells you, apart from the usual height, depth, width, that this character is part of a chain of characters implementing an extendable delimiter and if this one is too small try character octal 104.

Comment: Thanks! And oh so is \delimiter just some command we put at the beginning of the definition of another command to show it’s a delimiter? Also is it possible to find a translation table?

Comment: @galex-713 no `\delimiter` takes a following integer as a pointer into the existing font metrics. You can only use it to access characters that are already specified by the font metrics to be part of an extendable character sequence.

Comment: So that point to something defined inside some Metafont font, like Computer Modern? So like if I really wanted to know what does mean 6A and 0C (and maybe 3 too?) I should find this in the font sources?

Comment: @galex-713 I added some extra information about font metrics

Comment: Oh ok, but then what links `\vert` with `|`? what does mean `6A` btw? I can’t find `\fam3`, `\texfont3`, `\fam2`, etc. definition with latexdef…

Comment: @galex-713 -- the font-related commands you cite are only used in that form by plain tex.  for latex, an entirely different mechanism has been defined.  although it boils down to being able to access the same fonts and characters, it's not at all easy to untangle the latex code that does it.

Comment: @galex-713 you tagged the question tex-core so mostly I answered in terms of tex primitives only giving the latex macro wrappers as illustration if they were more readable.

Comment: @galex-713 "what does mean 6A" it's hex for the number 106 which just happens to be the slot where the  large vert character is in the cmex10 font.