# Detect delimiter

Tags: tex-core, conditionals, latex3, delimiters

Is it possible to check whether a token is a delimiter, i.e `(`, `)`, `|`, `\vert`, `\langle`, `\rangle`, etc without directly checking each of them in a condition?

The structure of delimiter is well described here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/296650/213149. It appear to use `\delimiter` command

So my question is how I can detect such a delimiter in somewhat versatile way using either pure TeX or LaTeX3.

For example, I want to custom macro `\isDelimiter{...}` to print `true` or `false` in the document if it's argument is a delimiter or not respectively.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure this can be useful for your `\veca` problem. Anyway…

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\isDelimiterTF}{mmm}
 {
  \antshar_isdel:Nnn #1 { #2 } { #3 }
 }

% first check whether #1 is a control sequence
\cs_new:Nn \antshar_isdel:Nnn
 {
  \token_if_cs:NTF #1
   {
    \__antshar_isdel_cs:Nnn #1 { #2 } { #3 }
   }
   {
    \__antshar_isdel_char:Nnn #1 { #2 } { #3 }
   }
 }

% it is a control sequence; first check the two exceptional cases \{ and \}
% which return true; otherwise go on: if the token is not expandable return false
\cs_new:Nn \__antshar_isdel_cs:Nnn
 {
  \str_case:nnF { #1 }
   {
    {\{}{#2}
    {\}}{#2}
   }
   {
    \token_if_expandable:NTF #1
     {
      \__antshar_isdel_csexp:Nnn #1 { #2 } { #3 }
     }
     {
      #3
     }
  }
 }

% the token is expandable, access its expansion
\cs_new:Nn \__antshar_isdel_csexp:Nnn
 {
  \__antshar_isdel_exp:onn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }

% if the expansion begins with \delimiter return true, otherwise false
\cs_new:Nn \__antshar_isdel_exp:nnn
 {
  \__antshar_isdel_exp_aux:w #1 \q_nil \q_stop { #2 } { #3 }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__antshar_isdel_exp:nnn { o }

\cs_new:Npn \__antshar_isdel_exp_aux:w #1 #2 \q_stop #3 #4
 {
  \token_if_eq_meaning:NNTF #1 \delimiter { #3 } { #4 }
 }

% when the token is a character, look at its \delcode;
% if positive return true, otherwise false
\cs_new:Nn \__antshar_isdel_char:Nnn
 {
  \int_compare:nTF { \delcode`#1 > 0 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\verb|a|: \isDelimiterTF{a}{T}{F}

\verb|(|: \isDelimiterTF{(}{T}{F}

\verb|]|: \isDelimiterTF{]}{T}{F}

\verb|\langle|: \isDelimiterTF{\langle}{T}{F}

\verb-\|-: \isDelimiterTF{\|}{T}{F}

\verb|\{|: \isDelimiterTF{\{}{T}{F}

\verb|\lbrace|: \isDelimiterTF{\lbrace}{T}{F}

\verb|\mbox|: \isDelimiterTF{\mbox}{T}{F}

\end{document}
```

[image]

How do we recognize when a control sequence is a delimiter? Its first level expansion should begin with `\delimiter` or, if a character, its `\delcode` should be positive.

The check for a character is therefore obvious. For a control sequence we need first to see whether it is expandable or not. But also we need to take care of `\{` and `\}` that are somewhat special, so these cases are settled by themselves.

If the control sequence we're examining is not expandable, it is not a delimiter (maybe other exceptions like `\{` and `\}` must be added with some font packages). If it is expandable, we look at its first level expansion by calling

```
\__antshar_isdel_exp:onn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
```

so the `o` argument type will do the required one-level expansion. This will become

```
\__antshar_isdel_exp_aux:w #1 \q_nil \q_stop { #2 } { #3 }
```

The definition of `\__antshar_isdel_exp_aux:w` is

```
\cs_new:Npn \__antshar_isdel_exp_aux:w #1 #2 \q_stop #3 #4
 {
  \token_if_eq_meaning:NNTF #1 \delimiter { #3 } { #4 }
 }
```

so the first token in the expansion of the control sequence we're examining becomes `#1` and the rest up to `\q_nil` becomes `#2`. The rest, that is, `#3` and `#4` are the true and false text for `\isDelimiterTF`. The first argument is undelimited, hence it will take the first token in the input stream as its argument; the second argument ends when TeX finds `\q_stop`.

The strange `\q_nil` is there because if you try `\isDelimiter{\empty}{T}{F}` there would be nothing in the expansion; in this case `\q_nil` is taken as `#1` and `#2` is empty. But, since `\q_nil` is not `\delimiter`, all goes through.

Comment: Thank you so much! I appreciate that.

Comment: Can you explain how `\cs_new:Npn \__antshar_isdel_exp_aux:w #1 #2 \q_stop #3 #4 {...}` works? What does `\q_stop` do?

Comment: @antshar The expansion of the token is placed in the input stream and the first token in its expansion becomes `#1`, all the rest is `#2`. If the given token expands to nothing you'd have a problem, though. If you fear this, add a different quark before `\q_stop`.

Comment: Does it mean that `#1 #2` becomes first argument of `\__antshar_isdel_exp_aux:w` and `#3 #4` is the second one?

Comment: @antshar Not at all. I'll add some explanations.

Comment: I don't understand how quarks work, that's why I asked. I understand that during the definition `\cs_new:Npn` means that `\__antshar_isdel_exp_aux:w` is for `N`, `#1 #2 \q_stop #3 #4` are for `p` and `{...}` for `n`. And I don't understand how all of `#1 #2 \q_stop #3 #4`  will be treated by `\__antshar_isdel_exp_aux:w` after it's defined.

Comment: @antshar Quarks do nothing. They're used as signals to end delimited arguments.

Comment: It took me some time and a couple of examples to try out, but I think I got it. Thank you! Now I'm playing around with `\token_if_eq_meaning`, but I can't really make it to work directly without those nested function. How can I save unbraced single token to a variable? For example I want to compare first token from `{\rangle\langle}` with `\rangle` via `\token_if_eq_meaning`.